# Can I use node to power a web application on a separate server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications

I asked this *(voted to be too broad)* [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806482/adjusting-to-no-more-php-with-node-app-development/21806556?noredirect=1#comment33006695_21806556) while working my way through a starter book on node. Reading this book, I'm sure I'll learn the answer to this later, but I'd be more comfortable if I knew this up front:

**My Question:** Can I (efficiently) continue using a usual webhost such as iPage or GoDaddy to host my web application, building and hosting the front end in a simple, traditional manner through an Apache web server, and communicate with a separate Node.js server (my application back-end) via AJAX for queries and other things that I can more efficiently process via Node?

More specifically, would this be a bad programming practice in terms of efficiency and organization? In other words, would it be likely that a large scale commercial application would ever be handled via this method?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can separate the front-end of your web application and the APIs that power it.  In fact, this is a very common configuration, especially for "large scale commercial applications".

Where you draw the separation line between the two specifically depends on what you are doing, how you're doing it, and what your needs are.  Also, in terms of hosting, remember that if you're accessing something server-side across the internet, you're adding extra latency to everything.  Consider getting off Go Daddy and using another host that gives you more flexibility, such as a VPS provider.

Comment: That is a good idea. Am I correct in assuming that I will need to learn to setup and configure my own apache web server in order to use a VPS?

Comment: @JonathanTodd Yes, that's correct.  When you get a VPS, it is very much like setting up physical hardware.  However, I think you will find this easy to do.  Digital Ocean (best cheap VPS host in my opinion, btw) has several tutorials:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts

Comment: Thank you. That gives me a place to start

Comment: And with Node.js, you'd probably not use Apache but Nginx. Take your time as it's really worth it.

Comment: There is no particular reason for choosing Nginx over Apache for Node.js.  Both can proxy to your Node.js app.  Nginx is definitely better than Apache at just about everything, but that isn't because of Node.js.  I also recommend Nginx, but let's be clear about why.  It's threading model is much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok. Actually, this is how things shoud be done. You have a backend API on a separate server and lots of apps which are using the API. Just go with Nginx server, check this [Apache vs Nginx](http://blog.webfaction.com/2008/12/a-little-holiday-present-10000-reqssec-with-nginx-2/).

Comment: what does nginx have to do with the question? it's not like node.js can't go toe to toe with nginx in the performance metrics that the linked post compared to apache...

Comment: @dandavis If you are comparing Nginx to Node.js, you are likely misunderstanding the purpose of both.  Node.js is an application server plaform.  Nginx is a web server.  If you're serving static files with Node.js, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @dandavis It's just a friendly suggestion to use Nginx instead of Apache if you care about performance and scalability.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use node js as a part of some big application. It depends on wich type of interaction you would like to get. Is it comfortable to you to mix technologies? Then node is pretty good thing to work over web. I've finished a part of big nodejs-ruby-php-c-flash application (my part was nodejs) for very large data mounts. This application have different levels of interaction. Sometimes I use 2 languages at one time to create each part of my application the best for task I'm working on. There is applications that initiate, run and destroy mutiple OS instances. So using of multi environmental application not so hard.